# Unable to Assign Reserved IP in Azure

Tags: azure, networking, ip, static-ip-address

I am facing an issue regarding IP assignment in Azure. Recently IP assignment is Dynamic i want to change in to Reserved but on portal i am unable to see this option editable/enable to do change and through command line i have no command like New-AzureReservedIP. Can anyone help regarding this? I will be very thankful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can do this using powershell you can use the following script:
Before executing make sure that the Public IP Address Resource is not associated with running Network Interface.

```
 Login-AzureRMaccount

$PIPName = 'Public IP Name'
$ResourceGroupName = 'Resource Group Name'


$PIP = Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name $PIPName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
$PIP.PublicIpAllocationMethod = "Static"  
Set-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -PublicIpAddress $PIP
Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name $PIPName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
```

More details find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/AzureRM.Network/Set-AzureRmPublicIpAddress?view=azurermps-6.8.1).

Answer (score 0):

To change IP assignment to Dynamic to Static:

VM => Go to Settings => Networking => Click on Public IP => Settings => Configuration => Assignment: Static.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If it is not configured to VM, then you can directly select Public IP from the resource group and change accordingly.